# Cannot use syncfusion for angular

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I'm trying to use syncfusion in angular in order to use Geomaps.
(https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/maps/getting-started/)
When I try to execute my component I obtain this error:

> **ERROR in The target entry-point "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-maps" has missing dependencies:
>
> - @angular/core
> - @angular/common**

I tried to execute *npm install*, to add the exact path of angular core in my projects, but it doesn't work.

This is my package.json file

> `    {

```
"name": "prova",
"version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
 "ng": "ng",
 "start": "ng serve",
 "build": "ng build",
 "test": "ng test",
 "lint": "ng lint",
 "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "~10.0.14",
 "@angular/common": "~10.0.14",
 "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.14",
 "@angular/core": "~10.0.14",
 "@angular/forms": "~10.0.14",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.14",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.14",
 "@angular/router": "~10.0.14",
 "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
 "tslib": "^2.0.0",
 "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.8",
 "@angular/cli": "~10.0.8",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.14",
 "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
 "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
 "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
 "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
 "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
 "karma": "~5.0.0",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
 "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
 "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
 "protractor": "~7.0.0",
 "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
 "tslint": "~6.1.0",
 "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
  }
```

`

This is my tsconfig file

```
{
 "files": [],
  "references": [
 {
   "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
 },
 {
   "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
 }
],

}
```

Comment: you have installed this component, because I don't see it in your package.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for contacting Syncfusion support.

We are not able to reproduce the reported issue. We suspect that the mentioned packages are outdated in your package.json file. We have updated the necessary packages in the application and created a sample application for your reference. It can be downloaded from the following link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Maps-1025419634.zip

In the above angular sample, we have rendered a world map with GeoJSON data.

Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

Regards,

Sabari Anand